# How do I draw a table of squares on tkinter canvas based on a table (list of lists)?

Tags: python, list, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

it's me again :)
I'm carrying on on my game project. I'm stuck (as the beginner I am) on this thing:
I have a table (list of 4 lists of 4 elements each. The length is flexible though, this is only a simple example for the question).
so here is my code:

```
from tkinter import*
l=[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
n=len(l)    #this is the length of the list l
lngt=400/len(l)    #this is the dimension of the squares that I want
fen=Tk()
fen.geometry("600x400")

#I would like to create a table of 4 rows on canvas
#each row should contain 4 squares
can=Canvas(fen,width=450,height=400,bg="lightblue")
can.pack(side=LEFT)
for i in range(n):
  can.create_rectangle(n,  i*(lngt)  ,n+lngt,  i*n+(i+1)*lngt,     fill="red")

f=Frame(fen,width=150,height=400,bg="lightcoral")
f.pack(side=LEFT)

fen.mainloop()
```

As of now, I only get a column of 4 squares on the left side of the canvas. All my trials have failed to create the 12 other squares.

Thank you awesome people!!

Comment: Try having a `for` loop within a `for` loop.  The outer loop could be for the columns, while the inner loop is for each row within one of the columns.

Comment: What do you mean "the 12 other squares"? That `l` has a length of 4, so `n` is 4. What's the purpose of `l`? The code you posted doesn't use it, apart from calculating its length.

Comment: I tried so, but it didn't change much. I tried with a "j" yet I don't really seem to know where to use the "j".

Comment: @PM2Ring, the `l` is the list I am using. I did not wish to use 4 as a length because I wanted it to be flexible. the list I joined is only for demonstration.

Comment: _How_ are you using `l`? Your code does _nothing_ with the data in `l`.

Comment: Later on, I would like to link my canvas to the data in `l` (coords of the elements in `l`)

Comment: But maybe I don't have to use it this way. let me try.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks guys, I removed the l, adapted the code a bit and it worked! here is the solution found:

`for i in range(n):` line break `for j in range(n):` line break `can.create_rectangle(i*n,  j*n,  i*n+n,  j*n+n,  fill="red")`

Comment: Sorry for the messy comment ^^>

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to draw a square grid of squares on a Canvas.

```
import tkinter as tk

l = [[0,0,0,0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
n = len(l)      #this is the length of the list l
lngt = 400 // n #this is the dimension of the squares that I want

fen = tk.Tk()
fen.geometry("600x400")

#I would like to create a table of 4 rows on canvas
#each row should contain 4 squares
can = tk.Canvas(fen, width=450, height=400, bg="lightblue")
can.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

for i in range(n):
    y = i * lngt
    for j in range(n):
        x = j * lngt
        can.create_rectangle(x, y, x+lngt, y+lngt, fill="red")

f = tk.Frame(fen, width=150, height=400, bg="lightcoral")
f.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

fen.mainloop()
```